# How can I enable Intellisense Quick Info in Less using Web Essentials 2013?

Tags: less, intellisense, web-essentials

I am working on a Less file which can be used by a very large team to ensure their CSS adheres to the specifications (as it's not always feasible to just use the core CSS files). I want to make it as easy as possible for them to do it. Intellisense helps with autocomplete and a nominal understanding of parameters for Less mixins.

But I really wish I could also use the Intellisense comment syntax to provide documentation as developers type.

For instance:

```
.-spec() {
  /// <summary>Returns full properties and values to match spec</summary>

  .button(@alpha: a; @omega: z) {
    /// <summary>Core button. Adheres to K4576.1</summary>
    /// <param name="alpha" type="String">Some description about alpha</param>
    /// <param name="omega" type="String">Some description about alpha</param>
    @var1: value1;
    @var2: value2;
    @var3: value3;

    .btn {
       background: @var1;
    }
  }
}
```

It would be great to be able to display the summaries for the mixins from the autocomplete, and to document the proper use of each parameter being passed to the function.

So, how can I get the Quick Info content to show up in Visual Studio 2013 SP3 using WE2013?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the less files in the same way you would in JavaScript files in Visual Studio.

**Example**

```
/// <reference path="mixins.less" />
```

This will give you auto complete intellisense when typing and also details of the mixin when you hover over it.

Comment: It may not have been clear, but I mentioned that autocomplete is already working. I want for the summary and other parameter info in the syntax above to work. Using WE2013 with VS2013, update 3, I do not need to add the reference for the basic stuff to work.

Comment: I was unclear in last comment. I don't need ///<reference... when I am already importing the mixin file, and adding it had no additional effect.